# Understanding AngularJS App Routing

Tags: angularjs

I am beginner in AngularJS and I find it hard to understand the flow.

I have a HTML to start with and given a link there

```
< a href="#/secondHTML"> GO < /a>
```

When I click on the `'a'` tag where it should go.
- to the state named 'secondHTML'
- to the HTML named 'secondHTML'

Please explain in detail the architecture of AngularJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJS uses Routes. `#/secondHTML` is a route, which is usually mapped to a template partial, which contains the HTML needed to render the view.

Usually inside app.js is where the code that configures your routes will be.

The code probably looks like:

```
angular.module('isweb', [
  'isweb.controllers',
  'isweb.filters',
  'isweb.services',
  'isweb.directives',
]).
config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/secondHTML', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/page2',
      controller: 'page2Ctrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/firstHTML'
    });
}]);
```

Notice the config method, which takes the routeProvider, as well as the mappings between the URL and the actual URL for the partial template.

So when you go to: `#/secontHTML` AngularJS will actually request `partials/page2` from the server, and render that. However, the address bar will look something like `myapp.com/app#/secondHTML`

I **HIGHLY** recommend going through the [AngularJS tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial).

Comment: How we can achieve this using states?

Comment: Look at using Angular UI-Router.